# URL package interacting with indentfirst and changepage packages to insert spaces in path command

Tags: urls, changepage

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newlength{\anIndent}
\setlength{\anIndent}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\myPar}[1]
{
\begin{adjustwidth}{2\anIndent}{}
    \hspace{\anIndent}
    #1              
\end{adjustwidth}
}  

\begin{document}
\myPar
{
\path{C:\Data Temp\Cam.dat}
}
\end{document}
```

This is about as close to a MWE example as I can find. The problem here appears to be that the indentfirst and changepage packages are somehow changing something about how the url package works, and inserting an unwanted space after the "Cam" text in the path. Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: The minimal example is `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\newcommand\testcommand[1]{#1}
\begin{document}
\testcommand{\path{C:\Data Temp\Cam.dat}}
\end{document}` -- The issue depends one the fact that you are using `\path` as argument-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided commands by `url` are using equal mechanism like verbatim commands. So you have to handle it in a special way. In your case the package `cprotect` will help:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\def\testcommand#1{#1{}}
\begin{document}
\cprotect\testcommand{\path{C:\Data Temp\Cam.dat}}

\testcommand{\path{C:\Data Temp\Cam.dat}}
\end{document}
```

Or in your case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\newlength{\anIndent}
\setlength{\anIndent}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\myPar}[1]
{
\begin{adjustwidth}{2\anIndent}{}
    \hspace{\anIndent}
    #1              
\end{adjustwidth}
}  

\begin{document}
\cprotect\myPar
{
\path{C:\Data Temp\Cam.dat}
}
\end{document}
```

Fore more information see: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-verbwithin.html